# Can't get information from my table in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I am pushing a value into a table. But when i try to print it out in my `console.log` I get undefined, but I know I'm pushing a value that is not undefined.

```
    var attachmentIds = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
        uploadFileToServer(files[i]).then(function(data){
            console.log(data[2]);
            if(data[0]){
                completed();
            }else if(!data[0]){
                completed();
                uploadFileStatus.push({file: data[1].name, uploaded: data[0], message: data[2]});
            }
            attachmentIds.push(data[2]);
            console.log(attachmentIds[i]);
        });
    };
```

> [10:53:51.492] ""533d219fff0006d40ced67ab""
>   [10:53:51.493] undefined

Here is my 2 console logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are manipulating attachmentIds inside then(). This is handled asynchron. So you dont know which value i has when logging attachmentIds[i]. Try logging the whole array attachmendIds and you should see your data.